# get EditText data on another activity - android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a login field and I want to get this data and put on textView on another Acitivity, but there is one Activity between this two.

Follow what I have so far:
MainActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstPage.class);
                i.putExtra("username", loginField.getText().toString());
```

A third Activity:
        TextView textConta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textConta);

```
    textConta.setText("*" + getIntent().getExtras().getString("username"));
```

and the textView is empty. Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: You need to get the String in the middle Activity using this same method, and pass it on to the third Activity.  It should work then.

Comment: @DanielNugent Im doing this on the middle Activity `Intent i = getIntent(); i.getStringExtra("username");`

Comment: Sharedpreferences or have a global variable. sp is the way.

Comment: @CássioBruzasco Assign the value to a String in the second Activity: `String loginName = i.getStringExtra("username");` then when you open up the third activity, add it as an extra to the Intent: `i.putExtra("username", loginName);`  Or, it might be better to just save it in SharedPreferences, as the answers suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the activity where you have login field:

```
SharedPreferences login = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = login.edit();
 editor.putString("user", loginField.getText().toString());
 editor.commit();
```

In the activity where you want to display：

```
 SharedPreferences login = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
 String user = login.getString("user", "0");
textview.setText(user);
```

Comment: What did not work. can you be precise whats hapening

Comment: It was a whole another problem, I was starting the 3rd activity by using setContent not startActivity(Intent). Now its working. Thanks. How do I vote up? I dont have 15 rep yet

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your intent from 2nd `Activity` to 3rd.

Or as alternative solution, you can store the data that you want to pass between activities in `File`, `SharedPreferences`, `SQLiteDatabase` or other storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` very easily. Save the string in the first activity:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("username", loginField.getText().toString());
editor.apply();
```

Then get the string in any activities after that:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.getString("username", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use the static variable in a content class as follow:

```
public class User{
static string username = "xxxx";
}
```

you can get the username at any activity you want. Because this is only one variable I do not suggest to use SharedPreferences.

another way is using "application"

```
public class User extends application{
private String username= "xxxx";

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
}
```

and in another activity you can get the application class as follow method:

```
User user = getApplication();
String username = user.getUsername();
```

android Clipboard is third way the get the message you want.

Answer (score 0):

Once the activity is been out of focus,all the values got by it and the activity itself will be lost.so we have to take the values to the 2nd activity and then to the third activity.It is the only way.We can use intents for it and values can be stored in bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple DataHolder class

```
public class DataHolder {
    public static String SOME_STRING;
}
```

In one activity just set `DataHolder.SOME_STRING = editText.getText().toString();`

In the other access it

```
String abcd = DataHolder.SOME_STRING;
```

Relly simple right?